# i want show unique bidder of every products

Tags: mysql

I have four tables `1) Users` `2) Products` `3) Auctions` `4) biddetails`. users and products are master table and in auction table product id is there.And biddetail table all key is there productid, userid and auctionid.

Question : i want to see every products of unique bidder.

My query below:

```
SELECT `p`.*, `a`.`id` as Auctionid, `a`.`enddate` as Enddate, `a`.`startdate` as Startdate, `a`.`bidprice` as Bidprice, `a`.`bidtype` as Bidtype, `a`.`starttime` as Starttime, `a`.`endtime` as Endtime, (SELECT  username
FROM  (select bid_price,u.username from biddetail as b join users as u on b.userid=u.id where b.auctionid=Auctionid   group by b.bid_price,b.auctionid having count(b.bid_price)=1  order by b.bid_price asc Limit 0,1) t1 ) as Username FROM (`products` p) JOIN `auctions` a ON `a`.`productid`=`p`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `biddetail` b ON `b`.`auctionid`=`a`.`id`
 WHERE `a`.`status` = '0' AND `a`.`enddate`> '".$date."' AND `a`.`bidtype` = '1' GROUP BY `a`.`id` ORDER BY `a`.`id` desc
```

Comment: Please edit to include table columns and expected outcome samples to help explain

Comment: In the title you want to "i want show unique bidder of every products" and in the text "i want to see every products of unique bidder.". Perhaps you should give us a chance to understand what you want :)